# confusion in understanding error message when writing to .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

When trying to write a dataframe to csv I get the following error:

```
In [197]: schdfarrdf.to_csv(ss, sep=',')

[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 798, in inspect_request
    reply_content = self.do_inspect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 555, in do_inspect
    bundle = self.shell.object_inspect_mime(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1838, in object_inspect_mime
    return self.inspector._get_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 738, in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 838, in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):
  File "C:\Users\mtc20tfq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1466, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

the .csv file seems to write correctly, but I dont understand why the error occurs, or what it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a Spyder/ipython bug. You might be able to work around it by adding a second statement such as `0` here

```
schdfarrdf.to_csv(ss, sep=','); 0
```

so the REPL doesn't try (and fail) to interpret the result of the `to_csv` call.

Comment: many Thanks @AKX, I have no idea why that worked, but it did :)